# Headless WhatsApp on Linux in a VM to use Matrix bridge

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, android, whatsapp

I noticed that Element added a voice message feature lately, and it's amazing. Now I could finally use Matrix exclusively for literally all the services I use it for. However, moving Whatsapp into a VM somehow seems trickier than it needs to be...

Basically, I want to run Whatsapp, headless, on a remote server, in a VM - or container - to then link it up with Matrix, so I can run just Element on my phone instead of having to continiously run whatsapp on my phone.

Is that possible? I would have to fake the camera input at least once for the photo taking. But aside from that, I only plan to run Whatsapp.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar situation. I will try the following and let you know if that works:

Since the challenge is to scan the QR code you could try downloading it as an image through code and scan it with your phone. It has to be quick since the page resets the QR every minute I think. You can use FTP or SSH to open the image once it's downloaded.

I'm guessing you are using a disposable phone but that's the only way I can think of to get it setup without a GUI.

Comment: No, not a disposable phone - but I just want to slowly move away from WhatsApp and my family is migrating to Telegram but...it's taking them forever. So at least for a small bit of time, I have to keep it around - for them, and even some jobs I applied for used WhatsApp as well (which is annoying...). Hence I just need to run it headless "somewhere else". When its no longer needed, i can just kill the VM and be good.